# How can I determine which submit button that is pressed through PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two submit buttons in my form. One button for publishing the article immediately and one button for saving the article as a draft. How can I manage through PHP, not JavaScript, to detect which one that was pressed by the user when submitting the form? Appreciate any thoughts.

```
<button type='submit' name='publish' class='btn btn-success'>Publiser</button>
<button type='submit' name='draft' class='btn btn-success'>Lage som kladd</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check which of the two names is an existing key inside `$_POST`:

```
if(isset($_POST['publish'])) { ... }
else if(isset($_POST['draft'])) { ... }
```